# Jsoup element reference is not null, but its empty

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

im parsing a website using Jsoup library in android. HTML:

```
 <div class="item-content">
    <a href="http://recepty.vareni.cz/kureci-maso-se-smetanou-a-kari/" title="Kuřecí maso se smetanou a kari" class="item-image"><img width="58" height="58" src="http://www.vareni.cz/include/ir/mmm_obrazek/15503-3857345f46aa4b5d2d1f07e379ad0f87--c58xc58.jpg" alt="Kuřecí maso se smetanou a kari" /></a>
 </div>
```

I need to get all `a` after `<div class="item-content">`. Im using this:

```
 Elements parent = doc.select("div.item-content > a");
```

Everything is working fine unless there are no such `a` founds. Here occurs the problem:

```
//the reference to parent is not null, but parent is empty, maybe there are some invisible characters
if(parent != null){
   //reference isnt null, but should be
   Log.i("parent","parent:`" +parent.outerHtml() + "`");
   //i get parent:``
}
```

im really confused and dont know how to handle this. Any help is appreciated. :-)

**EDIT:** edited my question to make it more clear.
im using Jsoup 1.7.2

Comment: So what is your specific problem? The JSoup select API returns empty elements when nothing is found. http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html#select(java.lang.String, org.jsoup.nodes.Element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
if(parent != null && !parent.isEmpty()){
    ...
}
```

That will check if `parent` is null or if it is empty